# Automatic ID for Datastore Embedded Entity (NodeJS Client)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Related to: [Automatic ID for embedded entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483254/automatic-id-for-embedded-entity)

I am looking to do the same thing in NodeJS as what's done in the linked post in Java, but given that there is no Entity or EmbeddedEntity type in the Node version of the library (as far as I can find), I am not sure how to do this. I am saving an array of embedded entities, each of which has 2 keys on it. I would like to be able to automatically generate a value on-save for a key, lets call it `embeddedEntityKey`, without worrying about generating random values in my code. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you confused with two terms here.
In java a lot of work is done by client library, including rich datastore mapping technics. In node, there are two kinds of entities that you can store inside parent entity.

1. You can specify a property and put object into it. In this case you
   will just write ordinary object into property and this wouldn't
   become and embeded entity.
   Example:

   ```
   db.save({ 
       key: db.key(["SomeKind"]), 
       data: { 
           object: {
               someVal: 1
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. You need to specify parent id in order to create true embedded entity.

   ```
   db.save({ 
       key: db.key({
           path: ["SomeParentKind", "ParentIdOrName", "EmbededEntityKind"]
       }), 
       data: {
           someVal: 1
       }
   });
   ```

Shortly saying, in Node.js embedded entity creation mechanism is different.
Here you can find more details about working with datastore on Node.js environment.
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-basic-entity-nodejs

Specifically, look at the ancestor section in documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths

**Update 2**

Save possibilities with Datastore in Node.js.

Save after get

```
db.get(db.key(["MyKind", db.int("123123123")]))
    .then(results => {
        let entity = results[0];
        entity.prop = 1;
        return db.save(entity);
    });
```

Initial save with write key into object

```
let object = {
    prop: 1,
    [db.KEY]: db.key(["MyKind"])
};

db.save(object);
```

Initial save with passing key as save argument

```
let object = {
    prop: 1
};

let key = db.key(["MyKind"]);

db.save({
    key: key,
    data: object
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely informative (I think I have been embedded entities incorrectly), *but*, I am mostly just looking to auto-generate an ID value on some field, and I see in the docs that providing an incomplete key should do that. In my case when I write `key = datastore.key('article_id')` I get the error `Error: Key path element must not be incomplete: [article_id: ]`

Comment: Datastore will generate it automatically. Which operation do you trying to execute with that key?

Comment: I place the key into an an object, which is appended into an array that exists on my User object. I then run `datastoreClient.update(userEntity)`

Comment: So, you need to create those instances first, or provide some value into the key by yourself. Datastore can't store incomplete key. It's meaningless to store incomplete keys. How do you appending key to user entity, by the way? There might be an issue as well.

Comment: My userEntity is a pre-defined kind and I use an OAuth ID as the key. Oddly enough the documentation says that if you run save/update with an entity that has incomplete keys, the key value will be automatically generated by GCD, which is exactly what I want!

Comment: How exactly, in the code do you write key into that entity? By default, there are two ways to define key for entity when you doing save/update. The first one in the is to define it in the object that has ```key``` and ```data``` properties, and the second, is to attach to object key using datastores' KEY symbol. Which one do you use? In addition, what you mean predefined kind?

Comment: I currently *don't* write a key in, the entity is just an entity value added into an array on the actual top-level user entity

Comment: How do you perform save operation?

Comment: Added it to the original post

Comment: I've updated my answer. Which one do you use to save original record? Is one of those approaches doing the job for you?

Comment: I use the first approach you list (except I use `update` instead of `save`), but the issue is that the thing I am trying to do is add keys to index on `entity.arrayProp` (example name). So I fetch the entity, and into entity.arrayProp I save an updated array.  I would like to do `entity.arrayProp.push({key: 'randomlyGeneratedKey', data: dataObject});` and then perform `db.update(entity);` but when I try to generate the key, I get the error I was listing, that the key path is incomplete, which in the docs is listed as a valid way to get a randomly generated key.